# some files have "A" or "C" or "AC" or others. What do these mean?

Tags: windows-server-2003

In Windows Server 2003, in the "Attributes" column of windows explorer, some files have "A" or "C" or "AC" or others. What do these mean?

Answer (score 2):

Found your answer over on superuser.

https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values

Comment: Aha, so the one I'm missing is Compressed

Answer (score 1):

"A" is the archive bit. It's set whenever a file changes, and backup software will check or clear the bit depending on what type of backup is running (full/incremental will clear it, differential/incremental will check it).

"C" is set when the file is compressed (in windows, when "compress contents to save disk space" is checked on the file/folder)